# VBS adding values from loop to array

Tags: vba, loops, ms-word

I have a VBS that finds the next track change in a word document and then presents a message box with the page number.

This loops through and it's not a problem, but what I was to do is add these 'CurPage' variables to a single array. So rather than msgbox 36 then msgbox 38 -- it is msgbox 36, 38 etc.

Also I need to work out end of file to exit the loop.

```
Dim i As Integer
i = 0

'get us home
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory

Do
'find next change
    WordBasic.NextChangeOrComment

'get current page
    CurPage = Selection.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
    MsgBox (CurPage)

'<Add CurPage value to array>

'<find out if we have reached the end of file, if so end loop>


  i = i + 1
Loop Until i = 188
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll address your first question; you need a separate post for the second one (about exiting the loop), as it's a totally different topic.

You don't need an array. You need a string you can display with `MsgBox`.

```
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim Pages as String

  i = 0
  Pages = "";    

  'get us home
  Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory

  Do
    'find next change
    WordBasic.NextChangeOrComment

    'get current page
    CurPage = Selection.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
    Pages = Pages & ", " & CurPage

    '<Add CurPage value to array>

    '<find out if we have reached the end of file, if so end loop>

    i = i + 1
  Loop Until i = 188
  MsgBox Pages

End Sub
```